# AWS ELB(Classic) failing to mitigate SYN flood DoS attacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ddos

I have been running a small back end for our mobile app using Elastic beanstalk for almost a couple of months now. The environment is on Amazon Linux 1 (Docker), Django application running inside Docker with the default nginx reverse proxy that comes with the Docker environment.

For cost reasons, we had started with a single instance environment (without any load balancing). We have launched a closed beta since then and had everything working fine for a few days until tragedy stuck yesterday when our application stopped responding to requests.

Upon investigation, we found that the CPU was running at 100% (`ksoftirqd` was stuck at 99%). Upon checking `dmesg` output, sure enough, a SYN flood attack was detected on port `443`. `netstat` also confirmed the SYN flood, with Cloudwatch showing 1.3 Gbps of constant traffic, resulting in complete network outage.

We fixed this temporarily by quickly deploying another single instance environment and swapping the URL's to replace the active environment and in the meantime wrote up configs for a load balanced environment (Classic load balancer with `TCP:443` passthrough to instances as we have mutual TLS authentication, on two `t3.medium` instances). We tested it and waited for the attack to happen again. Sure enough, the attack started as expected and we swapped the URL's of the single instance environment with the load balanced one. According to various aws docs, AWS shield standard should protect the ELB from passing through SYN floods to the instances, but unfortunately the load balancer became unreachable within minutes of swapping the URL. Surprisingly, the instances were still reachable through and showed standard output when we tested HTTP with curl and their own instance private IP, however, sibling instance were not reachable from each other using each others private IP's.

What followed was utter madness, as we had to manually shuffle environments for nearly three hours before the attacker lost interest and chose to stop, for now.

Is there any way this can be solved? Is AWS shield standard SYN flood mitigation failing because of the TCP passthrough to our instances. According to our knowledge, a passthrough is the only way to perform mutual TLS authentication using AWS load balancers. Are there any alternatives?
Also, shouldn't 2 t3.medium instances in tandem be able to handle a 1.3 Gbps surge?

We have

1. Tried enabling SYN cookies, increasing the SYN queue size, decreasing SYN retries.
2. Put in iptables rules in our instances to rate limit SYN requests.
3. Explored Cloudflare, unfortunately mutual TLS is enterprise only.

AWS shield advanced is way beyond our reach. This issue is severely impacting our relation with users, I would be grateful if someone can suggest a solution to this.

Comment: There is also AWS WAF that can be used. A tutorial for DDoD architecture is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-tutorials-ddos-cross-service.html) as well as AWS DDoS [whitepaper](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/DDoS_White_Paper.pdf) with more info and examples.

Comment: Both Cloudfront and WAF don't seem to support mutual TLS authentication which is critical to my workflow, so I guess terminating SSL on my own servers is the only choice I have.